# AlarmManager does not set alarm at 2 am daily

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I want the AlarmManager to set an alarm at 2 am daily... So below `setAlarm` is called only the first time someone opens the apps. I have added `alarmManager.setRepeating` so that it occurs daily.

```
public class AlarmUtil {

    public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Intent in = new Intent("ALARM_RECEIVER");
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
            calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd , yyyy  HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
        }
    }
 }
```

The below class is what should get called at 2 am daily irrespective of whether app is active or inactive.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, AlarmService.class));
    }
```

But my problem is the above AlarmReceiver gets called every 30 seconds or somewhat occurs randomly, but occurs many times, whereas I want it just to get called once a day. I don't understand where am I going wrong?

Comment: Btw, you set hour to 0 and minute to 2, that is 00:02, not 2:00.

Comment: @MarcEstrada thanks. actually while editing here, I made that mistake, but in my actual code its defined properly, still doesn't work :(

Comment: When and where are you calling setAlarm()?

Comment: in onCreate() method in MainActivity

Comment: It seems correct. Try to post more code. Also, if you want inexact repeating you should use `setInexactRepeating()`

Comment: @MarcEstrada just observed, if I comment the alarmManager.setRepeating line, still the broadcast receiver gets called. But how is it getting called from different places, there is only one intent with "ALARM_RECEIVER"?

Comment: Do you call `setRepeating()` in other places?

Comment: This was the main culprit `android:exported="true"`.. Thank you so much for the help, it got resolved.

Comment: so the problem was on the manifest?

Comment: Great! Maybe is you change the action to something more "yours" the problem would be fixed without change the Manifest. For example `your.package.name.ALARM_RECEIVER`

Comment: You should use explicit `Intent` for this purpose, otherwise any other apps that use `ACTION="ALARM_RECEIVER"` will inadvertently launch your app. Instead of setting the ACTION, just explicitly set the component with `new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class)`